# How to use a variable inside an indirect function in vlookup() vba formula?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using `Do Until ()` formula to paste vlookup formulas in cells that are "Active".

I am using "i" as a variable to change the cell rows. I can't use "i" when I am calling it inside the indirect function in the vlookup formula. I think the double quotes I use are not right. Please help!

```
Sub Overtime()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range, c As Range

    i = 6
    Do Until (Cells(i, 3) = Active)
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
    Range("E" & i) = "=vlookup($A" & i & ",indirect(""'""&$H$3&""'!A:AZ""),1,FALSE)"
    Range("F" & i) = "=vlookup($A" & i & ",indirect(""'""&$H$3&""'!A:AZ""),2,FALSE)"
    Range("G" & i) = "=vlookup($A" & i & ",indirect(""'""&$H$3&""'!A:AZ""),3,FALSE)"
    ***Range("H" & i) = "=vlookup($H$3,indirect(""'[ATTENDANCE.xlsm]$G""" & i & """'!A:AZ""),35,FALSE)"***
    Range("I" & i) = "=vlookup($A" & i & ",indirect(""'""&$H$3&""'!A:AZ""),7,FALSE)"
    Range("J" & i) = "=vlookup($A" & i & ",indirect(""'""&$H$3&""'!A:AZ""),28,FALSE)"
    Range("K" & i) = "=vlookup($A" & i & ",indirect(""'""&$H$3&""'!A:AZ""),36,FALSE)"
    i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

I expect formulas in cell H6 to "Active" cells to be

```
=VLOOKUP($H$3,INDIRECT("'[ATTENDANCE.xlsm]"&$G6&"'!A:AZ"),35,FALSE)
```

The Range "G6" should be auto-filled in the next cells as G7, G8 and so on until cells(i,3) is Active

**Sample Screenshot:** 
[image: Preview of Excel Sheet]

Comment: What is `Active`? This variabele is not declared. Make sure you use `Option Explicit`. I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.

Comment: Active is just a text in a cell. If the cell contains Active then the formulas are pasted. I have error in the 9th line.

Comment: Here `Cells(i, 3) = Active` it is a variable not a text! Strings are always surounded by double quotes `""` if not it is considered as a variable. Make sure you use `Option Explicit` and you will see it.

Comment: You probably meant to use `"=vlookup($H$3,indirect(""'[ATTENDANCE.xlsm]""& $G" & i & " &""'!A:AZ""),35,FALSE)"`

Comment: But still you should fix the other issues I mentioned because your code definitly does not what you expect.